# QuickTime Player: "cannot open http://... because it is not a valid URL." due to pipe character

Tags: quicktime, video-streaming

A URL for a video stream from some news website I'm trying to load contains pipe characters (`|`). Although this media URL loads fine inside the flash video player of the website, as well as in VLC, QuickTime Player throws this error.

If I remove the pipe character the URL is considered by QTPlayer as valid but it doesn't point to the proper content...

Any ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace the pipe characters in the URL with the encoded version `%7C`.

So `http://www.name.com/file|place` would be `http://www.name.com/file%7Cplace`.

More info on URL encoding [here](http://www.blooberry.com/indexdot/html/topics/urlencoding.htm) and [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding).